# Test for significant difference between two probability distributions sampled from a model

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, importance-sampling

Let's say I use importance sampling to sample conditional probability distributions for variable X (categorical variable with 3 levels) 50 times, for example,

P(X|Y=1) = { (0.11, 0.21, 0.68), (0.09, 0.22, 0.69), ... }

P(X|Y=0) = { (0.20, 0.25, 0.55), (0.15, 0.23, 0.62), ... }

What sort of a test should I use to test for significant differences between the sampled categorical distributions between P(X|Y=1) and P(X|Y=0)?

EDIT:
I can think of a t-test to look for differences between individual levels, e.g. between P(X=1|Y=1) and P(X=1|Y=0), i.e. {0.11, 0.09...} and {0.20, 0.15...} and so on. I think that would be a valid way of comparing means of sampled probabilities.

Is there a way of comparing the categorical distributions themselves? I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: At first, what’s the purpose of the test? You may consider using MLE or simple tests for difference in means.

Comment: I do not understand the question as it mixes the evaluation of the difference between two distributions, $P_0$ and $P_1$, and the Monte Carlo variability due to an importance sampling, $\hat P_0$ and $\hat P_1$,

Comment: @Xi'an So I'm guessing a t-test would be appropriate for testing whether the difference in means between the estimated probability distributions is significant, which would account for the variability in sampling. I guess I'm looking for guidance on how I can check whether the sampled categorical distributions are significantly different, not the individual probabilities for each category.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the $\chi^2$ test for homogeneity is designed for. For some reason I could not find it in the English language wikipedia, but the German language wikipedia [has an article about it](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-Quadrat-Test)  (see section 4). Maybe someone can provide an English language reference in the comments.